# Angular 2 http request audio src not play

Tags: angular

I obtained data on and attached to the audio src but it does not run.

detail.component.ts

```
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() detailName: string;
    @Output("playnhac") play = new EventEmitter();
     private linkmp3:string;
    constructor(private _http:Http) {

    }
ngOnInit() {
                    this._http.get('http://searchsong.azurewebsites.net/api/mp3File/'+this.detailName+'&type=128&key=minhtaitr')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
          data => {this.linkmp3=data

        })

        }
```

detail.component.html

```
<audio controls>

  <source type="audio/mpeg" src="{{linkmp3}}" >

</audio>
```

Comment: do you receive http response?

Comment: yes , url correctly but will not turn on

Comment: try ``[src] = "linkmp3"`` and make it ``public linkmp3``

Comment: I have tried but not effective

Comment: @raj no need to add public , if you are using that variable within the same class/template you can use private too.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use interpolation in attributes, instead `[attr.src]="..."`.
Also you will not be able to set this attribute without this pipe:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'safe',
    pure: true
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform
{
    private sanitizer:DomSanitizer;

    constructor(sanitizer:DomSanitizer)
    {
        this.sanitizer = sanitizer;
    }

    transform(url)
    {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: tks. it's great hint

Comment: may i know whats the need of this pipe in playing audio ? also better please if you provide any workling example something like plunker.